# MS Word showing two different sets of Built-In Table of Contents

Tags: ms-word

I am rewriting our product documentation and am encountering an issue with the built-in table of contents templates.  For all of our documents so far the built-ins have looked like this:

[image: Typical Table of Contents]

However on this specific document I am seeing this and I can't have it:

[image: Abnormal Table of Contents]

This is the same exact version of word and the two documents are saved as the same file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Built-in" table of contents goes off of the current document's [style set](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563).

Go to the 'Design' tab and compare the selected option between your two documents. Changing the incorrectly formatted one to the same style as the other should fix your problem. If you don't want to change the whole document style, it is possible to make a custom table of contents, but this will be much trickier than just unifying the styles.